# Check if a div content contain a word from an array and replace it

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, contains

I want to check if a div's contents contains a word from an array and add some tags like `<b></b>`  to that word.

Here is my code:

```js
var fruits = ["banana", "peach", "grappe", "lemon", "apple"];
          $( ".mystr" ).each(function() {
            mystr =   $( this ).html();
           if (fruits.some(function(v) { return mystr.indexOf(v) >= 0; })) {
// get the fruit and replace it with <b>thefruit</b>
//and print it in a div   
//"<div class='mynewstr'></div>"
           }      


            });
```

```html
<div class='container'>

    <div class='mystr'>I love apple </div>
    <div class='mystr'>I don't  like banana</div>
    <div class='mystr'>I don't  like peach</div>
    <div class='mystr'>I  like both grappe and lemon</div>


    


    </div>
```

for exemple for

```
<div class='mystr'>I love apple </div>
```

must become

```
<div class='mynewstr'>I love <b>apple</b></div>
```

Any Idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be the most performant solution since it is iterating all fruits for each string, but if your fruits and `.mystr` set is not super big it should not be a problem:

```
var fruits = ["banana", "peach", "grappe", "lemon", "apple"];
$( ".mystr" ).each(function() {
  mystr = $( this ).html();
  fruits.forEach(f => {
    mystr = mystr.replace(f,`<b>${f}</b>`, 'g')
  }) 
  $( this ).html(mystr)  
});
```

Here's a codepen with it working
https://codepen.io/ederdiaz/pen/QJmmvg

Comment: yes EderChrono, unfortunately my fruit table is quite big.

Answer (score 3):

One option would be to `join` the fruits into a global regular expression (which will match any fruit substring), and then `.replace` the `html()` of every `.mystr` div with `<b></b>`s surrounding the fruit words:

```js
const fruits = ["banana", "peach", "grappe", "lemon", "apple"];
const pattern = new RegExp(fruits.join('|'), 'g');
$(".mystr").each(function() {
  $(this).html(
    $(this).html().replace(pattern, '<b>$&</b>')
  );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='container'>

  <div class='mystr'>I love apple </div>
  <div class='mystr'>I don't like banana</div>
  <div class='mystr'>I don't like peach</div>
  <div class='mystr'>I like both grappe and lemon</div>
</div>
```

(note that `$&` in a replacement string gets replaced with *the entire matched substring* for that match)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, your solution is working as expected but is it ok if you know that  in reality  my fruit table may contain more than 4000 entry ?

Comment: I think it'll still work, though if you're working with that much data, it might take a bit longer than expected. Also, for something like this, you should consider fixing it *server-side* rather than client-side, I think, if it takes up any significant CPU time

Comment: Did it work for you? When an answer solves the problem you're having, consider marking it as Accepted to indicate that the issue is resolved :)